# Can variables be stored in Lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

Can I do this in python?

```
lst = [listItem = 0,listItem2 = 0,listItem3 = 0]
```

Then update the variable in the list like:

```
number = 1

if number > 0:
  lst[1] += 1
```

`listItem2` is now = 1

Comment: Welcome to SO ! You can use [dictionnaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

Comment: @Aymen why? This looks like they want a _list_.

Comment: I'd suggest just starting with a python tutorial in general - what you're describing is a list, not a dictionary, but SO really isn't the place to start learning the basic syntax. Get an environment you can run code in and mess around with syntax copy-and-pasted from tutorials for a while.

Comment: Or don't just copy-paste code from tutorials -- actually understand what it does, and see if you can write code to do the same thing as the tutorial yourself. Then compare it with the tutorial. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) and a search engine of your choice are your best friends when you're learning

Comment: @PranavHosangadi it looks like (key, value) thing. He assigned a value for each `listItem`. In lists you can't add a name for your values.

Comment: @Aymen they later access `lst[index]`, not `lst[key]`, so it looks like a regular list. I suspect `listItem1`, `listItem2`, etc. are _names_ that they defined previously that they want to store in a list.

Comment: If you try to run `lst = [listItem = 0,listItem2 = 0,listItem3 = 0]` you get a `SyntaxError` so clearly you can't do that in Python.  What are you really asking?

Comment: @Raman, if you have variables named `listItem1`, `listItem2`, etc. and want to modify those variables by modifying the list, then that is not possible if those variables point to integers (or other immutable types). This concept is more advanced than "noob" level (your words), so I'd suggest you do some tutorials to level up from noob level first :)

Answer (score 0):

Well for the first if you want store data in list just put them like this:

`List = [0, 1, 2]`

not this: `List1 = [var1 = 0, var2 = 1]`

if you need to make variables from data stored in list just use them like this:

`var1 = List[1]`

This how your code should look like:

```py
lst = [0, 0, 0]

number = 1

if number > 0: 
    lst[1] += 1
```

Comment: Best to use code tags with code  - makes for a more readable response.

Comment: Also not a good idea to use `list` as the variable name for a list.